# Split array elements into another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have one string array:

```
string[] A = new string[2] {"abcde", "gpfag"};
```

How can I split this array like this:

```
A[1] = new string[5] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
```

Any idea?

Comment: That obviously wouldn't work, as `A` is a `string[]` and not a `string[][]`, so you certainly cannot do this in-place. You need a `string[][]` and then it's just a string split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A[1].Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(A[1][i]);
}
```

Results:

```
g
p
f
a
g
```

See it work here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/I6UGBQ

The only difference is it's read-only; you can't assign characters back into the string by position. But you can still do this:

```
A[1] = new string(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'});
```

Note this uses `char` values, because a string is a sequence of characters. What you wanted wouldn't work, because you were trying to use a sequence of one-character strings, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this code helps you.

```
var charArray1 = A[0].ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can't do it [**in-place**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033837/c-sharp-modify-an-array-in-place-without-creating-another-array-in-memory) as [Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141621/camilo-terevinto) suggested in the comments, you have to store the flattened result in a new collection.

You can use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) to flatten the initial string array and further use [`ToCharArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray) extension method to flatten the string and map it back again to strings as `ToCharArray` converts it to individual characters.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] A = new string[2] { "abcde", "gpfag" };
            string[][] flattened = A.Select((item) => item.ToCharArray().Select((inner) => new String(inner, 1)).ToArray())
                                    .ToArray();             

            foreach (string[] outer in flattened)
            {
                foreach (string inner in outer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(inner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputting -

```
a
b
c
d
e
g
p
f
a
g
```